# iPhone SDK - How to know how contacts are ordered and displayed in the default Contacts app?

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I'm working on a app with Facebook integration.

When I list Facebook contacts, I would like to use the same 'Sort Order' and 'Display Order' as in the Contacts app on the device. The way contacts are displayed on the default Contacts app, can be adjusted in the Settings app.

My question is, do you know if I can access those settings in order to have my Facebook contacts list displayed exactly as the Contacts app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Part of this question (Sort Order) has been answered already - [Retrieve iPhone Address Book sorting preference programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067934/retrieve-iphone-address-book-sorting-preference-programmatically)

As for display order, use `ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormat`, also from [ABPerson](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html)