# Retrieve iPhone Address Book sorting preference programmatically?

Tags: iphone, addressbook

Is it possible to detect the sorting technique used by the Address Book on a particular user's phone? (For instance, "sort by last name" or "sort by first name".)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABPersonGetSortOrdering)

```
ABPersonGetSortOrdering
Returns the user’s sort ordering preference for lists of persons.

ABPersonSortOrdering ABPersonGetSortOrdering (
   void
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Never considered that it was a "Person" attribute...seems like an attribute of the overall Address Book.